# Passport-Facebook authentication window not popping up, user still added

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

So, when I first ran the app yesterday, the authentication screen appeared as normal. Ever since then, even after deleting myself from my mongodb database, the authentication window does not pop up.

I've been searching for a solution but none have worked. I've also cleared my cookies, did not work either.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas you guys have!

**auth-routes.js**

```
router.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook", ({ display: 'popup' })));

router.get("/facebook/callback",
    passport.authenticate("facebook", {
        failureRedirect: "/auth/login"
    }), (req, res) => {
        res.redirect("/")
    }
);
```

**profile-routes.js**

```
const authCheck = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.user) {
        res.redirect("/auth/login")
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

**passport-setup.js**

```
   passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user.id)
    })
});

passport.use("facebook", new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.clientID,
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    User.findOne({ userID: profile.id }, (err, user) => {
        if(user) {
            console.log("Already a user");
            done(null, user)
        } else {
            new User ({
                userID : profile.id,
                userName : profile.displayName
            }).save().then((newUser) => {
                console.log(" ")
                console.log("New user created! ===> ")
                console.log(newUser);
                done(null, user);
            })

        }
    })
}))
```

**server.js**

```
    app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use("/auth/", authRoutes);
app.use("/profile/", profileRoutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, admittedly I feel a bit silly. I figured it out.

Facebook only authenticates you once, in order to show the authentication screen more than once, you'll need to remove permissions on your facebook settings.

In hindsight, this should have been common sense lol. I hope this helps someone in the future if the situation comes up.